# open php file from another

Tags: php

how can we redirect(open) a php file from another php file without using action method??

Comment: What exactly is this action method? Do you mean HTTP redirects? And what do you mean with open? It would help if you could point out to a URL where the desired mechanism is in place.

Comment: while you're question is not the best, i can't see why someone would down-vote and not leave any feedback.

Comment: I meant by action method the one used in the form <form action="">

Answer (score 5):

To read a file from a php script user [fopen() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

To redirect a user to a new php page user the [header() function](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) with the location header value.

If you want to see an example i invite you to check this link: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm

==[EDIT]==

Now that you have explained a little bit more what you are trying to do here is some additional information.

The action attribute indicates to which file the form should submit its data to. If you do not specify this attribute the form will be submitted to the current page.

The method attribute can be either equals to POST or to GET. GET means that your values will be sent as arguments in the URL, POST means that your values will be sent to the page through the $_POST superglobal.

I'm not sure to clearly understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1 for accounting for the major possibilities in this *extremely* open ended question

Comment: Keep in mind that `header()` function must be used before anything is outputted to your page and should be used like this `header("Location: http://www.example.com/");`

Comment: @fahmi i added some additionnal information about the action and method attributes. Please check them.